# Django on AWS EC2 unable to connect, regular Python connects

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection

I am trying to run the development version of Django from the [Github dev code](https://github.com/django/django). The code is running on an [AWS EC2 instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), and I'm running Firefox on my local desktop ([Kubuntu Linux](http://www.kubuntu.org/)). When I try to connect I get this error:

> Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 1.2.3.4:8000.

I know that I have the firewall, AWS security groups, and VPS set up properly as I can access the port when starting a normal Python web server:

```
$ python3 -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
bzq-241-14.net - - [16/Mar/2015 10:17:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
bzq-241-14.net - - [16/Mar/2015 10:17:29] code 404, message File not found
bzq-241-14.net - - [16/Mar/2015 10:17:29] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
bzq-241-14.net - - [16/Mar/2015 10:17:29] code 404, message File not found
bzq-241-14.net - - [16/Mar/2015 10:17:29] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
^C
Keyboard interrupt received, exiting.
```

However, the Django server doesn't even register a rejected connection:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 16, 2015 - 11:00:30
Django version 1.9, using settings 'Reboot.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

**What might be the cause of the connection issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development server is bound to localhost and not accessible from other machines. You can set the port via a parameter as documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port .

But of cause the best way would be to deploy Django properly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. I've independently discovered it and posted an answer, but I'll accept your answer as soon as the SO system lets me. This is in fact a test system. Apache will deploy the production site when it is ready.

Answer (score 1):

On a hunch, I tried starting the server with the IP address and port of the server, that did not help:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 1.2.3.4:8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 16, 2015 - 11:08:43
Django version 1.9, using settings 'Reboot.settings'
Starting development server at http://1.2.3.4:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to.
```

However, **starting the Django server with the LAN IP address** did help:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2a:da:26:29:39:8e  
          inet addr:10.0.0.101  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::28da:26ff:fe29:398e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:535102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:364585 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:333175535 (333.1 MB)  TX bytes:183546758 (183.5 MB)
          Interrupt:43 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:12760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:988343 (988.3 KB)  TX bytes:988343 (988.3 KB)

$ python manage.py runserver 10.0.0.101:8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 16, 2015 - 11:09:08
Django version 1.9, using settings 'Reboot.settings'
Starting development server at http://10.0.0.101:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[16/Mar/2015 11:09:11]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1767
[16/Mar/2015 11:10:04]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1767
[16/Mar/2015 11:10:05]"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1941
[16/Mar/2015 11:10:05]"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1941
```

Thus, on AWS (and possibly all remote servers) one must **start the Django server with the LAN IP address** in order to access the remote test server.

Answer (score 0):

**Might help a beginner or someone new to AWS**

I knew I had to add some rules to the security groups but I didn't knew exactly which ones so here are the rules that you should add

[Go To -> EC2 > Security Groups > your-security-group > Edit inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWy5I.png)

after this you have to start the django server using the following

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And now you can access your django app on :8000 of your EC2 public domain

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).